# How to build Woocommerce payment gateway with iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, payment, gateway

I am working on building a custom wordpress woocommerce payment gateway.  I am following this tutorial "https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-woocommerce-payment-extension/", the issue is that i am not using the direct payment method, and instead i need to use iframe based or external page.
I need to know how to redirect to the external page/iframe, make the payment and get the result back.

anyone can change the tutorial code or help?  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you "need" to use an iFrame? What restriction do you have that requires iFrames, rather than embedding in your site?

Comment: it is kind of how PayPal, it follows the PCI compliance.

Comment: You can do PayPal without an iFrame, and maintain PCI compliance.  iFrames for this sort of application are *not good*, and should be avoided.

Comment: OK then, how to redirect to their landing page, process the payment and get the result back?

Comment: So you are aware that WooCommerce **has** a PayPal add-on, right? Depending on the version of PayPal.  For [Standard](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/), or [Pro](https://www.woothemes.com/products/paypal-pro/)

Comment: @cale_b yes i am aware, but i am not building an add-on for PayPal, i am building it for a payment gateway which is similar to PayPal.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not sharing the details? Is it confidential which payment portal you are using?  It's difficult to advise how to do this when we can't even know what API options are available to you.

Comment: Just FYI An Iframe woocommerce gateway *is* a supported gateway type. They are used for PayPal-like payment processing where the payment occurs on a different site. The question is about this type of gateway https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to insert an iFrame?

Comment: If you got a solution please share here.

Comment: @AmjadAta-Allah Can you please let me know which PayPal payment gateway do you want to migrate in Iframe?